# Sqlite calculate difference in days between YYYYMMDD date formats in Query

Tags: database, sqlite, timestamp

I have stored treatment date (tdate) and received date (rdate) dates in YYYYMMDD format for some patient records. I wish to query records that the result of rdate - tdate is less than 30.

My attempt was

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (rdate - tdate) <= 30;
```

Somehow this is a valid query but the results are something else. Let me know if you have a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite doesn't actually have a native storage class for timestamps / dates. It stores these values as **NUMERIC** or **TEXT** typed values depending on input format. Date manipulation is done using the builtin date/time functions, which know how to convert inputs from the other formats.

You will probably need to cast your date fields to a number of days, using the **julianday** function to perform the subtraction, otherwise they'll likely be typed as strings.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (julianday(rdate)-julianday(tdate)) <= 30  ;
```

[Here is the documentation about SQLite data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Your query is valid, because the subtraction operator implicitly casts its operands to **NUMERIC**. What these numerics resolve to will depend on the actual format of the date values you have stored in your fields. You could see this by using a query that explicitly lists these casts.

```
SELECT rdate,tdate,
       cast(rdate AS NUMERIC), cast(tdate AS NUMERIC),
       rdate - tdate 
FROM table ;
```

Which should make it clear what is happening in your original query.

Answer (score 2):

I was able so work with the answer @cms wrote and this is what worked for me.

```
SELECT *,(julianday(substr(rdate`,1`,4)||"-"||substr(rdate`,5`,2)||"-"||substr(rdate`,7`,2))-julianday(substr(tdate`,1`,4)||"-"||substr(tdate`,5`,2)||"-"||substr(tdate`,7`,2)))'difference' FROM table WHERE difference <= 30.0
```

It worked like charm